# How to save date upon page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to display the date when I click the button for each item in a mysql query.
Each item has a button and when I click on it I want to display the current date. and when i push again the same button for the same item the date should update

I used this code :

```
<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

but when I refresh the page I want to have the last date saved (still displayed)

Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: did you consider using sessionStorage or localStorage to store the last date ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this:

1. define a property for [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage): `let myStorage = window.localStorage;`
2. Check if your property exists already in your storage, if exists set the `p` text with the value from there
3. At click, set the new value of your property with the current date using `new Date();`

```js
let myStorage = window.localStorage;

// when you refresh the page, set the p text to the existing value from localstorage
if (myStorage.getItem('myBtnTime')) {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myStorage.getItem('myBtnTime');
} else {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Nothing saved, please click the button";
}

function setDate() {
  myStorage.setItem('myBtnTime', new Date());
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myStorage.getItem('myBtnTime');
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="setDate()">Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can use session tosave Date()

**sessionStorage()** remember the last value.

***To use it like this***

```
sessionStorage('key', 'value');
```

***Full Example***

***HTML***

```
<button type="button" onclick="ambildate()">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

***Js***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var p = document.getElementById('demo');
p.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('current');
});

function ambildate(){
var p = document.getElementById('demo');
var T = Date();
p.innerHTML = T;
sessionStorage.setItem('current', T);
}
```